# Creating segue from programmatically created table view

Tags: ios, swift, segue, programmatically-created

I am new on iOS development, after completed some basic tutorials and beginner level books, i looked the examples of iOS programming. After that i found this.

https://github.com/uacaps/PageMenu

I downloaded examples, but i have a problem. I am using PageMenuDemoTabbar (https://github.com/uacaps/PageMenu/tree/master/Demos/Demo%204/PageMenuDemoTabbar)
example. And i want to add segues when user clicked the tableviewcell. But here is the problem. Because tableviews created programmatically, i can't add segues from storyboard.

How i can accomplish this?

Thanks for help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to go to another view controller from the Storyboard, just add StoryboardID to this view controller (like I have RootViewController with StoryboardID **RootVC**):

[image]

then create public property for the data you want to pass to the view controller (i.e. `@property (nonatomic, strong) NSDictionary *propertyYouSet`).
And then add the following code in your `-tableView:didSelectItemAtIndexPath:` UITableView delegate method:

```
YourViewController *yourViewController = [[UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]] instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"YourViewControllerStoryboardID"];
yourViewController.propertyYouSet = @{ 'someKey': 'someValueYouWantToPass' };

[self.navigationController pushViewController:yourViewController animated:YES];
```

This way you can still use Storyboard view controllers without need of segue.

### Swift version

Oops, just noticed the `swift` tag. So here is the same code in Swift:

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
    let vc = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("yourViewControllerStoryboardID") as! UIViewController
    vc.setYourProperty(someDictionaryHere) // I'm not so sure about this, I'm new in Swift too :)
    self.presentViewController(vc, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

then override this method in your view controller:

```
init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder!)
{
    super.init(coder: aDecoder)
}
```

(because in Swift `-initWithCoder:` is required :) )

Comment: would be nicer combined into the other answer :)